# Deploying BQ schema changes to QA and production projects

Tags: google-bigquery

We have the BQ tables existing in production. We would like to make changes to the schema structures i.e. need to add additional columns. We wouldn't want to manually add the columns to these tables as there are many such tables. What is the best way to push the schema changes through a deployment solution?

Comment: what ingestion method are you using: streaming API, load API, others ?

Comment: We are doing a batch load via Airflow using standard GCS to BQ load operator

Answer (score 0):

As you have multiple tables I suggest to use BQ [patch](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables/patch) API embedded in your deployment script which can be written in most of the existing common development language e.g: JS, Python etc ([Client Libraries](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries))

Alternatively, you can use [BQ command line](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool) for this if it's better suitable to your deployment process.

This [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-table-schemas) provides an explanation on what can be changed in the schema and what are the limitations.

> bigQuery natively supports the following schema modifications:
>   * Adding columns to a schema definition
>   * Relaxing a column's mode from REQUIRED to NULLABLE

The limitations are:

> All other schema modifications are unsupported and require manual workarounds, including:
>   * Changing a column's name
>   * Changing a column's data type
>   * Changing a column's mode (aside from relaxing REQUIRED columns to NULLABLE)
>   * Deleting a column

It also provides a detail explanation on how to attach the `JSON` schema object to any of your prefer method

Answer (score 0):

When patching tables you could either maintain your latest schema template as a dedicated table or as a separate table definition. That would allow you to script your patch operation with the language of your choice.

You can also consider [endly automation runner](https://github.com/viant/endly/).

In that case, you would just define a workflow calling BigQuery API to perform a patch.

```
endly -r=patch authWith=myGoogleSecret template='my_project:my_dataset.myTableTempalte' dataset=mydataset criteria='narrowing_value' '
```

[patch.yaml](https://github.com/viant/endly/blob/master/system/cloud/gcp/bigquery/usage/patch.yaml)

```
init:
  'gcpCredentials': $params.authWith
  gcpSecrets: ${secrets.$gcpCredentials}
  projectID: $gcpSecrets.ProjectID
  '!template': $params.template
  '!dataset': $params.dataset
  '!criteria': $params.criteria
  i: 0


pipeline:
  registerSource:
    action: dsunit:register
    datastore: ${dataset}
    config:
      driverName: bigquery
      credentials: $gcpCredentials
      parameters:
        datasetId: $dataset

  readTables:
    action: dsunit:query
    datastore: $dataset
    SQL: SELECT project_id, dataset_id, table_id  FROM `${projectID}.${dataset}.__TABLES__` WHERE table_id LIKE '%${criteria}%'
    post:
      tables: $Records


  patchTable:
    loop:
      action: print
      message: Patching $i/$Len($tables) -> $tables[$i].table_id

    patch:
      action: gcp/bigquery:patch
      logging: false
      template: $template
      tableId: $tables[$i].table_id
      datasetId: $tables[$i].dataset_id
      projectId: $tables[$i].project_id
      credentials: $gcpCredentials

    inc:
      action: nop
      init:
        _: $i++
    goto:
      when: $i < $Len($tables)
      action: goto
      task: patchTable
```

You can also find more [endly patch examples here](https://github.com/viant/endly/tree/master/system/cloud/gcp/bigquery#schema-patch)